# Best way to convert a field in Rails from decimals to integer in cents

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I have a Product model in Rails and the amount is stored as an integer in cents in the database.

Example of this field:

[image]

- What is the best way to allow admins that are creating the product to enter a human-friendly decimal like 10.00 instead of 1000?
- Should I just do this on the client-side before the form is submitted with Javascript?
- Should I change the field to a text field instead of integer and convert it with a before_save callback?

It seems like the [Money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) might be overkill for this.
Surely this is a common problem. What is a common way people solve this?

Comment: You can have a numeric `<input>` field which accepts decimal values by specifying `step="any"` or `step="0.01"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as ideas

Using money gem

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  monetize :price_cents
end
```

```
= f.input :price
```

Or using monkeypatching

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def price
    self[:price] / 100.0
  end

  def price=(value)
    super(value * 100)
  end
end
```

In my opinion gem is more convenient

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just going with the Money gem (specifically the 'money-rails' gem)